# C++ user defined function is not invoking in vs2010 while debugging in some C++ function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Actually here i am tring to invoke some user defined function from 1 function. But i couldnt step-in in to that function, i dont know what could be the reason.

below is the code snippet for calling function

```
if (!m_pCSock->ConnectTo(aszTWinServerName, m_szServicePort, false))
```

and below is the defination for the above call

```
int CSocketClient::ConnectTo(const char *szSuppliedHostname, const char *Suppliedport, bool ShowErrors)
{
    if (m_Connected)
    {
        return m_Connected;
    }
    char    szHostname[128] = "";
    char    port[128] = "";
```

The above 2 instances are in different projects and different files.

I tried a lot, I coudn't invoke into this function.

While debugging, when I try to invoke the below line

```
if (!m_pCSock->ConnectTo(aszTWinServerName, m_szServicePort, false))
```

it is not moving inside this, it is just moving to next statement.

I am suspecting here it might be some setting issue, I am actually to Windows.
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with "different files"? Different *.dlls? You need the *.pdb for the project you want to debug (step in).

Comment: do you have some sort of optimizations on in debug build? is there something that might have corrupted the stack prior to the call? we need probably a SSCCE to be able to help you (http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 0):

maybe the file that contains the function is not built in "debug" mode.

If you perform a "clean and build" operation over the library or proyect, forces the file to be compiled with debug symbols and then debugger can visit that code.